# Why I am not able send header with /(forward slash) like character?

Tags: java, ios, http, encoding, afnetworking

I am getting cookie value in `jstring`. Server is sending it as *base64encoded UTF8* string. I compared string from server and my end, and I am getting exactly same string.

Now I need to decorate this value with `n=` as prefix and `;` as suffix. (Which I am doing in *line no. 2* of code).

If I do not use line no. 1, string goes null to Java Server. Otherwise server is getting value.

```
jstring = [jstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *cookieVal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n=%@%@",jstring,@";"];
[self.requestSerializer setValue:cookieVal forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

We are using `AFNetworking` in iOS for request and response. We have observed very strange pattern,

If string contains `/`(forward slash) then we are getting *padding error* on Java server, if string doesn't contain `/`, then string will go as required.

As you can see in line no. 3, we are sending this value as header of http/https request.

I have tried many things, like [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/95636-read-write-utf-8-strings-between-iphone-and-java-application-using-sockets.html) (tried very last code with my string.). Also, tried to use different encoding, but problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This url conversion would not convert all the special characters we have in ios device keypad.
we have to convert this with blow function. use this as category.

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString_ch {


    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)self,  NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]%~_. ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)));
}
```

Comment: I am using same code / is converting in %2F, try to convert two times it maybe some decoding going on server end.